# Qt state charts: How to invoke a compiled state machine?

Tags: qt, statechart, scxml

Having read the [SCXML invoke example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscxml-invoke-static-example.html) I ask myself how this should work if you want to invoke a state machine that was compiled to C++ code using `qscxmlc`. I noticed that it is possible to invoke another state machine by using the `src` attribute in the `invoke` tag. I got this working by setting `src` to the filesystem path of an SCXML file. I could however not figure out how to refer to an SCXML file in the Qt resources (using `qrc:///...` did not work) or how to invoke a compiled state machine.

**Update**

I could not find anything in Qt's documentation so I had a look at the sources (version 5.8):

Loading is implemented in `qscxmlcompiler.cpp` in `QScxmlCompilerPrivate::DefaultLoader::load(..)` (line 2447):

```
    const QUrl url(name);
    if (!url.isLocalFile() && !url.isRelative())
        errs << QStringLiteral("src attribute is not a local file (%1)").arg(name);
    QFileInfo fInfo = url.isLocalFile() ? url.toLocalFile() : name;
#endif // BUILD_QSCXMLC
    if (fInfo.isRelative())
        fInfo = QFileInfo(QDir(baseDir).filePath(fInfo.filePath()));
    // ...
```

I notice that it uses QUrl and therefore should be able to work with resources I tried using `:/mystatemachinefile.scxml` instead of `rsc://mystatemachinefile.scxm` and it worked :) This however should be added to the docs IMHO.

I still wonder how you should implement state charts if you want to compile them before they are used, but I guess this is not possible at the moment?

Comment: When you write `rsc:///` did you literally use that or did you mean you used Qt Resource URLs, i.e. `qrc:///`

Comment: I meant I used Qt Resource URLs, I edited the question.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible at the moment :(

Comment: In your update you are again using `rsc://` which won't work